# I have a bug with my "complexCard" widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

So, you'll see in the image that my "complex card" widget is doing things that I don't understand how it's even possible that flutter draws the widget like that.

I simply want that the 2 ElevatedButton that are in my code just draws below the "simpleCard" widget but it doesn't do so and instead the column does strange things.

```
 
    class PieceCardState extends State<PieceCard> {
  late Widget current;
  int flex = 1;

  Widget simpleCard() {`enter code here`
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0)),
      width: 10,
      height: 40,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          Container(
            // Future will be an image
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown, width: 4),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text('Level',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    fontSize: 36.0,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown, width: 4),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 218, 107)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget complexCard() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      width: 10,
      height: 60,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          simpleCard(),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30)),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('SWAP', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white)), style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.orange))),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('INFO', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white)), style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.orange)),)
        ],
      )
    );
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    current = simpleCard();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          current = complexCard();
          flex = 2;`enter code here`
        });
      },
      child: current,
    );

  }
}
```

[That is the difference between simple card (left) and complex card (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ggDa.png)

Comment: Please add the image link of widget you want to create

Comment: I just want to create the simpleCard widget but with 2 ElevatedButtons below the widget. The simpleCard is the left card in the link below my code
The 2 ElevatedButtons are "swap" and "info", they are on the right widget.
I want to merge the appearance of the left widget with the 2 buttons on the right and that's what the ideal appearance of the widget I want to create

Answer (score 0):

There might be several things creating this issue for you.
For starters, you are setting a very low `width` and `height` for the container of your **simpleCard**, **complexCard**.

Remove those properties because they are not doing anything, and it will solve your issue.